# Invalid output in C program on Linux

Tags: c

I'm writing a similar program on C on Ubuntu. The task is to show the output on console. I am using gcc compiler. The task is to get such an output `12, Name Surname, 36, my lapt, -11`, but instead i get `12, apt, 36, my lapt, -11`. I know that my program is overwriting `a` at `strncat(d, c, 4);`, but i don't know the reason why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char a[] = "Name";
char b[] = "Surname";
strcat(a, b);
int x = strlen(a);
int y = strcmp(b, a);
char d[] = "my ";
char c[] = "laptop";
strncat(d, c, 4);
int z = strncmp(a, c, 2);
printf("%d, %s, %d, %s, %d\n", x, a, y, d, z);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` only has space to store 5 bytes, including string terminator. You can't `strcat` anything into it - you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: d is not big enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char a[] = "Name";
char b[] = "Surname";
strcat(a, b);
```

is wrong. `a` does not have room. It's size is only 5. This would work:

```
char a[20] = "Name"; // 20 is arbitrary, but it's big enough for the strcat
char b[] = "Surname";
strcat(a, b);
```

Same goes for the `d` array

This can be read in [documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

> `char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );`
>
> *[The parameter `destination` is a]* Pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

Always read the documentation for functions you're using.